# Windows Phone 8 Development: OpenStreamForWriteAsync not working?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

this is my first post here on stackoverflow and i hope I'm doing everything as I am expected.
I've already used the search function but I found nothing that could help me.

The problem I am having has to do with the OpenStreamForWriteAsync() method that is used to open a stream to a file. Sometimes the code executes as expected (the stream is opened, I write my stuff etc.). But on other occasions the program just exits at the point where I await the stream. It doesn't throw any exceptions so I have no idea why it does that.

Here is the code:

```
class MyDataSerializer<T>
{
    public static async Task SaveObjectsAsync(T sourceData, string targetFileName) {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(targetFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var outStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();//PROBLEM HERE
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(outStream, sourceData);
        await outStream.FlushAsync();
        outStream.Close();
    }

    public static async Task<T> RestoreObjectsAsync(string fileName) {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        var inStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        T data = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream);
        inStream.Close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs at line 5!
Just to clarify this: both methods in the class DO work. It's just that the SaveObjectsAsync sometimes DOESN'T work and I have no idea why.
While debugging I set breakpoints at all lines but when the mysterious problem occurs, the debugging session just ends without any exceptions (yes, I set VS 2012 to show every kind of exception there is) and the data is NOT serialized so that when I start the app again, no data is loaded...

I hope my post wasn't too long and you guys understand the problem I am having.

Thank you guys in advance!

PS: The code is directly from one of the Jump Start videos provided by MS (at 31:00): [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-04-Files-and-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wait for the SaveObjectsAsync to complete?

You can do that either with the new `await` keyword, or (e.g. if you're calling it from the main thread of a console app) by calling `t.Wait();` method in the Task object returned by your SaveObjectsAsync.

Comment: Yes, I do. That is, the method that calls SaveObjectsAsync() is itself an async Task (VS kept telling me that i can't use await in a normal method so i made it async, too...sorry, I am new to c#). Maybe that is the problem?
It looks like this:
            public async Task SaveFavorites() {
            await MyDataSerializer<ObservableCollection<Favorite>>.SaveObjectsAsync(Favorites, "favorites.xml");
        }

edit: sorry, I don't know how to display code properly in a comment : (

Comment: I believe your application just quits normally (e.g. tombstoning, or back button).
If it happens before your SaveFavorites has finished, you’ll observe exactly the behavior you’re describing.
One way to fix that — explicitly `.Wait()` for the SaveFavorites task to finish while staying in Page.OnNavigatedFrom or Application_Closing.

Comment: In the Application_Closing method I tried App.ViewModel.SaveFavorites().Wait(); (that's what you mean?) but that didn't solve the problem either.
I just took another approach now and save the data everytime it gets changed instead of in the Application_Closing method!
So i guess my Problem is semi-solved : )
It works for now, though I would prefer to execute the code on closing...
But I have another question now if that's ok: does anyone know if the Contact class is serializable? Cause when i tried serializing my Favorites object, it wouldn't deserialize the Contact object within it properly.

Comment: Great. Now do the same (i.e. the `.Wait()` call) in your Application_Deactivated. Here's the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx If you'll do that, you'll no longer need to save the data everytime.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your 2-nd question (about the Contact class). You better ask a new question here on SO.

Comment: Well since I found a workaround for my problem, I guess I consider my question answered : )
Oh and the Contact class really doesn't seem to be serializable. But I also found a workaround for that. Not sure if it's the most elegant code but it does the trick for now haha.
Thanks man! : )